# Net::SMTPSyntaxError: 501 Invalid RCPT TO address provided

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mail-gem

As I understood I have issue because use not ASCII symbols in emails address

Example:

Notifier.rb

```
mail(to: "Tamón ÄRUÄ <example@example.com>", subject: "Email subject")
```

Any advice how I can handle this case? I prefer keep user name in address.

Comment: Is it `ActionMailer` or are you using `mail` gem standalone?

Comment: ActionMailer, but prepare email address via mail GEM "m = Mail::Address.new(email); m.display_name = full_name.dup; m.format"

Answer (score 1):

According to `ActionMailer` documentation multibyte encoding should be done automatically: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#auto-encoding-header-values

There might be several things to try:

1. Try adding `# encoding: utf-8` to the first line of your controller;
2. Try using `mail.transport_encoding = '8bit'` http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mikel/mail/Mail%2FMessage%3Atransport_encoding